# How to protect data in HTML5+PhoneGap mobile app?

Tags: javascript, security, html, obfuscation, cordova

Is it possible to protect sqlite database inside mobile app created using PhoneGap + HTML5 ? I have some big chunk of data, that I would like to protect. But from nature of used technologies it seems to me its almost impossible. If it's not possible to protect the data, is it at least possible to use some obfuscation to discourage "script-kiddies" to not try get to the data easily ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user of your software has more of a right to control the sqlite database than you do.  Your software is just a visitor on **his machine**.  Any form of encryption would be [security though obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) because you cannot have a secret (or secret key) on the device.

If you want to protect a database,  then you have to host it.   I recommend setting up a RESTful interface so that the js on the mobile device can perform actions on the data.  You should assume that the attacker has 100% access to this RESTful interface.  You should never expose a function like `do_query("select ...");`.  Make sure you take sql injection into consideration.

Comment: While your answer does make some good points regarding storing data securely, it does not provide a solution to the problem described by the OP. Specifically, how to secure data stored in an sqlite database on a user's device.

Comment: @cdeszaq  Correct, and the OP is asking for something impossible and i'm explaining why this is completely and totally impossible.

Comment: @Rook - I would argue that it is not impossible to meet the OP's needs, since the OP indicates that simple obfuscation to stymie the "script-kiddies" would be within the realm of possibilities that could be considered.

Comment: if you have data you don't want casual pokers-around to see, even rot13 is enough.  there's no reason to go further than that.

Comment: Thanks for answer, even though, I was kind of looking for some "security through obscurity" solution, mainly aiming "script-kidies", because I assume (as you have said) the client will have always access to the data. 

And regarding the RESTful interface you suggested - what should be resulting answer of this interface ? Wouldn't the "bad-user" be able get to the same data using this kind of access ?

Comment: @Frodik Well perhaps your business model is the insecurity.  An example of a secure restful interface would be exposing functions like `change_password()`  or `up_vote()` or `down_vote()`.  Your abstracting functionality and relying upon user access control.  Really your application is no different from a web app,  how would you prevent a browser from updating another user's password with a POST request?

Comment: @Frodik, in a RESTful web service, you never serve all the data, but only server the "answer" to a "question" that is asked by your app.  Therefore, your "data" is protected, unless the user generates enough questions to reverse-engineer your database.  If you're thinking that putting the data up in a RESTful server will mean serving it dynamically on-line, you'll need to rethink your connectivity paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do would be to encrypt the data as it goes into the database, and then decrypt it as it comes back out. To do this in a semi-maintainable way, you would need some sort of DB access layer where the encryption/decryption can happen so that your main app doesn't need to worry about it.

I'm not particularly well versed with PhoneGap, so I'm not sure if there are any existing plugins that do this. But, If you don't mind the hassle of encryption/decryption being coupled in with your app code, you could just pass everything through an `encrypt(myData)` function on the way into the DB and then through a `decrypt(myData)` function on the way out. This would work pretty well if you are only going to/from the DB in a couple of places.

This is a fairly heavy-weight solution, but as you said, the options are fairly limited.

Lastly, I would suggest using the device ID (if you can get to it), or some other per-account or per-device method of getting the encryption key so that each device is more difficult to crack, rather than all devices using the same key. A hash of the username or salted username or salted salted-hash hash of the password might all be good options.

Comment: Do you know if some kind of this DB access layer exists, that could be used within PhoneGap ? Searching for such plugin/extension didn't return anything...

Comment: @Frodik - I added more detail to my answer

Comment: Why the down-vote? What about my answer makes it a poor answer to the question asked? Are there better ways to secure data? sure, but not too many when the constraints are that it has to be secured in the environment given by the OP.

Comment: -1 THis is in no way shape or form a problem that can be solved with cryptogrpahy.  What you are describing is only a **VULNERABILITY**.

Comment: @Rook - In what way would this make the application more vulnerable?

Comment: @cdeszaq  The point is that you aren't defending against anything.   Its just as vulnerable as it ever was.

Comment: @Rook, I'm not sure I agree.  The OP requires protection of his data stored in the phone environment.  Data that is encrypted can still be accessed, but they no longer disclose anything meaningful, therefore fulfilling the OP's requirement for protection.  The point is that it is difficult to encrypt non-textual data and even more difficult to encrypt keys when foreign-key relationships exist, making the encryption approach less of a practical solution.

Comment: However, it **is** possible to encrypt every field of every table in the database to protect the data -- assuming similar protection of the encryption key in the PhoneGap-compiled application, which may require obfuscation if the encryption/decryption is performed in JavaScript.

Comment: @Stephen Chung  So then where are you going to put the key?  What stopping the user from loading up a debugger and putting a break point on the `encrtpy()` function and viewing the plain text and they and iv you are using?  (Of course I'm giving you the benefit of the doubt and assuming that you using a key with iv in cbc mode.)

Comment: @Rook, that's why I said in my comment "assuming similar protection of the encryption key ... which may require obfuscation".  The OP does not require absolute protection, only good-enough protection to "discourage script-kiddies".  The "decrypt" function does not have to be named "decrypt", and the JavaScript can be obfuscated to a point that reverse-engineering is all but impossible.

Comment: @Stephen Chung - Thank you for the support, but I don't think you are going to get anywhere with the (perfectly valid) reasoning than the OP doesn't need a _secure_ solution, just a _secure enough_ solution, even if, in the actual question, it was indicated that obfuscation would be sufficient. But I appreciate the support all the same. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could also encrypt your data with [JSAES: AES in JavaScript](http://point-at-infinity.org/jsaes), but then you will need to  have some sort of key-management mechanism with your server/user.